# How to get the type of a field in an annotation processor?

Tags: java, annotations, java-6, annotation-processing

I'm trying to write an annotation to check if an object is immutable at runtime. In order to do so, I check if the class of the object is final and then if all its attributes are also final. And then, I want to check the same thing recursively for the type of each field if it's not a primitive type.

Here a piece of code:

```
for (Element subElement : element.getEnclosedElements()) {
    if (subElement.getKind().isField()) {
        isFinal=false;

        for(Modifier modifier : subElement.getModifiers()) {
            if (modifier.equals(Modifier.FINAL)) {
                isFinal=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isFinal) {
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Field "+element+" is not immutable because it is not final");
        } else {
            // Here I want to restart my method recursively
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get my method to start all over again with the type of my field? How can I retrieve the type of the field, which is here a [`javax.lang.model.element.Element`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html)?

Edit: I need the type as declared in the containing class, which needs to be a final class to avoid any kind of mutability.

Comment: Why do you need to get the type of the field? Can't you just use `subElement` as the argument (i.e. `subElement` is used as `element` in the recursive call)?

Comment: @Greg Kopff: I need to check if the class of the field is final and if its own fields are final. A field is not a class...

Comment: I edited my question, as I wrote quite the opposite to what I actually needed in the last part. Unusual thinking and late hours...

Comment: I think what I'm looking for could be Element.getEnclosingElement(), but I can't find any example or tutorial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to do it with [Square's javapoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) `ClassName` class:

```
Element element = ...
ClassName className = ClassName.get(element.asType());
String name = className.toString();
```

If, for example, the annotated field is a `String`, it will return `Java.lang.String`. I'm open to a better solution than this one.

Answer (score 3):

I think

```
String type = element.asType().toString();
```

also gets the fully qualified name of the type of the fields.

Comment: Your `type` sting might also contain annotations and type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I never have needed `javax.lang.model` before. If you intend to check things at runtime, I'd go through `java.lang.Class` and `java.lang.reflect.Field` instead. There you can use `getType`to obtain the type of the field. You can also have a look at all fields, including inherited ones, using `getFields`. Or you can look at ancestor classes and their declared fields, to get at private ones as well.

**Edit: the following consideration appears to be no longer relevant**

Notice that even that type information will return the declared type, i.e. the type as it is written in the source code. The field might still hold a reference to a derived class at runtime. Possible counter-measures would be having all those classes declared `final`, so that there can be no derived classes, or tracing all assignments to those fields, which would mean major static data flow analysis. Not sure that's worth the effort.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the type declared in the containing class. I first wrote the opposite in the question, but I edited it. Sorry for that...

Comment: @Traroth, added a bit about how to get inherited fields.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's possible to go from the model defined in an annotation processor to Reflection.

Comment: @Traroth: That's the reason why I never had used `javax.lang.model` before. Either you do things at compile time. Then the annotation processor is your friend. Or you want to do runtime stuff. Then reflection will serve you well.